# behavior of "this" in forEach and addEventListener method

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, this, addeventlistener

Edit: This is not a question about general behavior of "this" keyword in different context.  My question is whether there is a common underlying logic behind the 2 behaviors here - is it because "this" only binds to an object when the method of that object is called, but forEach() is a method of an array?
Why is it that when I use:

```
var tag = ["a","b","c"];

tag.forEach(function () { 
  console.log(this)
});
```

`this` refers to the global object since the function is bind to the global object, but when I use:

```
element.getElementById("id").addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

`this` refers to the `id` element even though it's within a function? Is it because `forEach` is a method of an array rather than a method of an object?

Comment: Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Answer (score 1):

In DOM event handlers `this` is set to the element the event fired from:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_DOM_event_handler